# Place Graph on Kivy as a Widget with Button

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to put a graph that self updates. So when I press a Kivy button on my GUI script written with Python and it's supposed to take me to a `Screen`. The `Screen` has a graph on a part of the `Screen` and buttons on the rest of the screen. However, I add the graph and it opens in a separate window. How do I do that?

I used the `matplotlib` library for plotting the graph.

I used `plt.show()` and it opens a different window.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent `matplotlib` from stealing the focus of your `Window` you need to tell it to do so for some strange reason (maybe because of high usage of MPL in IPython notebook?)

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

After those lines the window should stop stealing. The updating on the other hand is something way different and that's why there's [`garden.graph`](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph/blob/master/__init__.py) and [`garden.matplotlib`](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.matplotlib).

If you intend to just draw some simple plots, just use the Graph. If you really need MPL and/or you want to do something complex, use the MPL backend (`garden.matplotlib`).

Comment: I believed that would be a backend and would not show the graph on the gui. Is there is a way for the code to export the graph so it could be seen?         Thank you.

Comment: Well, you can save the MPL plot to an image and load it into kivy image widget later (or just into bare texture), but I think you'll have more luck with `garden.matplotlib` instead of this workaround.